When ambushing Szeth, why doesn't King Hanavanar use bows or crossbows?
In The Way of Kings, there is a scene where the Assassin in White, Szeth, is attacking King Hanavanar during a feast. It is revealed that this feast was a trap for Szeth, with multiple shardbearers present to kill him, and armsmen with half-shard shields.
Szeth does not have shardplate. For the ambush, why are there no archers or crossbowmen set to kill him? It seems like killing a shardblade wielder from a distance is the best way to do it to me, and I'm trying to understand why, in universe, this wasn't done.

Hmm, I think they underestimated bows as weapons and I don't remember crossbows in the series. Still, Stormlight healing makes arrows more of a nuisance then a threat and they likely suspected he had it.
